# Efficient USD formatting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Say I have a string: 33400298.57

I've written a function (too long, too bloated, too substandard to post here) which formats this into:

33,400,298.57

The meat logic is the insertion of commas -  leftwards of the decimal, every three places. Can there be a one line solution using regex to accomplish this? Presently, I'm splitting, reversing, looping to insert, reversing and joining again. Needless to say, it's unoptimal.

I'm looking for something like this:

Random color generator: '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);

Thanks.

Comment: check this link: http://software.dzhuvinov.com/jsworld.html

Comment: Thanks, but really don't want to look up a library to find a line. That too a paid one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I format numbers as dollars currency string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-dollars-currency-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

How about this sexy little number with regex:

```
s = "33400298.57";
s.replace(/(?!^)(\d\d\d)(?=(\d\d\d)*\.)/g, ',$1'); // 33,400,298.57
```

Comment: It is a regex, but it is also sexy.

Answer (score 0):

Since I use jQuery on top of JavaScript, I would use a jQuery plugin.  Something like this:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/

If you are using a different JavaScript library I would look for a plugin for that library instead.  **I would avoid writing your own formatting method.  Don't reinvent the wheel.**

Comment: You don't need to write a whole method for a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's Number's `toLocaleString`:

```
Number(12345.67).toLocaleString();
```

It is locale specific however, so caveat emptor.